# Nested SELECT statement in DateAdd()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, nested

I am trying to get the `MAX()` of a column and use that value to perform a `DATEADD()` operation,

```
CONVERT(Datetime, DATEADD(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, MAX((SELECT tb_records.rec_record_date FROM tb_records)))) AS ExpiryDate
```

What I tried is this:

```
SELECT tb_files.file_pk AS 'File Number',
       tb_files.file_subject AS 'File Subject',
       CONVERT(Datetime, DATEADD(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, MAX(
                                                                           (SELECT tb_records.rec_record_date
                                                                            FROM tb_records)))) AS ExpiryDate,
       tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk AS 'Storage Number',
       tb_compartment.comp_part AS 'Compartment Number',
       tb_departments.dept_code AS 'Department',
       tb_location.locationno AS 'Location',
       tb_users.usr_fullname AS 'Created by',
       tb_files.file_datecreated AS 'Date Created'
FROM tb_files
INNER JOIN tb_fileparts ON tb_files.file_pk = tb_fileparts.fp_file_fk
INNER JOIN tb_records ON tb_fileparts.fp_pk = tb_records.rec_filepart_fk
INNER JOIN tb_users ON tb_files.file_createdby_usr_fk = tb_users.usr_pk
INNER JOIN tb_compartment ON tb_files. file_comp_fk = tb_compartment. comp_pk
INNER JOIN tb_cabinet ON tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk = tb_cabinet.cab_pk
INNER JOIN tb_location ON tb_cabinet.cab_location_fk = tb_location.location_pk
INNER JOIN tb_departments ON tb_cabinet.cab_dept_fk = tb_departments.dept_pk
WHERE (tb_files.file_active = 1)
  AND (tb_records.rec_active = 1)
GROUP BY tb_files.file_pk,
         tb_files.file_subject,
         tb_files.file_retentiondate,
         tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk,
         tb_compartment.comp_part,
         tb_departments.dept_code,
         tb_location.locationno,
         tb_users.usr_fullname,
         tb_files.file_datecreated HAVING(Convert(DateTime, DateAdd(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date))) <= getdate())
```

I get this error message:

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i think you might want (SELECT MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date) FROM tb_records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wrap a subquery with a MAX() function like that... Try this:

```
SELECT tb_files.file_pk AS 'File Number',
       tb_files.file_subject AS 'File Subject',
       CONVERT(Datetime, DATEADD(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, (SELECT MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date) FROM tb_records))) AS ExpiryDate,
       tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk AS 'Storage Number',
       tb_compartment.comp_part AS 'Compartment Number',
       tb_departments.dept_code AS 'Department',
       tb_location.locationno AS 'Location',
       tb_users.usr_fullname AS 'Created by',
       tb_files.file_datecreated AS 'Date Created'
FROM tb_files
INNER JOIN tb_fileparts ON tb_files.file_pk = tb_fileparts.fp_file_fk
INNER JOIN tb_records ON tb_fileparts.fp_pk = tb_records.rec_filepart_fk
INNER JOIN tb_users ON tb_files.file_createdby_usr_fk = tb_users.usr_pk
INNER JOIN tb_compartment ON tb_files. file_comp_fk = tb_compartment. comp_pk
INNER JOIN tb_cabinet ON tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk = tb_cabinet.cab_pk
INNER JOIN tb_location ON tb_cabinet.cab_location_fk = tb_location.location_pk
INNER JOIN tb_departments ON tb_cabinet.cab_dept_fk = tb_departments.dept_pk
WHERE (tb_files.file_active = 1)
  AND (tb_records.rec_active = 1)
GROUP BY tb_files.file_pk,
         tb_files.file_subject,
         tb_files.file_retentiondate,
         tb_compartment.comp_cab_fk,
         tb_compartment.comp_part,
         tb_departments.dept_code,
         tb_location.locationno,
         tb_users.usr_fullname,
         tb_files.file_datecreated HAVING(Convert(DateTime, DateAdd(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate, MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date))) <= getdate())
```

Comment: This works. Can I include an INNER JOIN (or some other command) on that statement so I can get the Max for record X, instead of all the records?

Comment: It will function just like any other subquery. You can add a JOIN, a WHERE clause, etc.

Comment: you already have `tb.records` as an inner join, all you need to do is change your expiry date column to just `MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date)`

Comment: @SoulTrain I think he's talking about limiting the dates that the MAX function will apply to by adding limiting criteria to the subquery in the SELECT statement...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty descriptive.  SQL does not allow you to use a subquery for an argument to an aggregation function.  The simple solution is to move the aggregation inside the subquery:

```
   . . .
   CONVERT(Datetime, DATEADD(MONTH, tb_files.file_retentiondate,
           (SELECT MAX(tb_records.rec_record_date)
            FROM tb_records
           )
          ) AS ExpiryDate,
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you max query to..

```
SELECT MAX(A.rec_record_date) FROM tb_records A
```

In the way you have written your query, the `MAX record_Date` of the entire table is going to be calculated over and over again for each row in your result set. I would that you rather create a `CTE/subquery` and reuse the value...